# SharePoint IF calculation needed to consolidate columns

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, column, calculated-column

Looking to solve this issue IF Brand = A, B, C or D, then 'Special Brand'; otherwise (Brand = E and) if Buying Status = 1 or 2, then 'Top Tier'; Otherwise 'Bottom Tier'

Answer (score 3):

**First Column [Brand] Formula**

```
IF(OR([Brand]="A",[Brand]="B",[Brand]="C",[Brand]="D"),"Special Brand","E")
```

If you need to show the `[Brand]` value if it's not equal A or B or C or D, then try the below one

```
IF(OR([Brand]="A",[Brand]="B",[Brand]="C",[Brand]="D"),"Special Brand",[Brand])
```

---

**Second Column [Buying Status] Formula**

```
IF(OR([Buying Status]="1",[Buying Status]="2"),"Top Tier","Bottom Tier")
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the following formula:

```
IF(OR([Brand]="A",[Brand]="B",[Brand]="C",[Brand]="D"),"Special Brand",IF(AND([Brand]="E", OR([Buying Status]="1",[Buying Status]="2")),"Top Tier","Bottom Tier"))
```

Result:

[image]